# How to prevent a started PHP session from writing?

Tags: php, session

I have a situation where I've started a session with:

```
session_id( $consistent_session_name_for_user );
session_start();
$_SESSION['key'] = $value;
```

but then later I decide I don't actually want to "commit" (write) this session. PHP doesn't seem to have any kind of `session_abort_write()` function. I don't want to destroy the session variables from prior script runs, so I can't use `session_destroy()`

I tried `session_id("")`, but that call fails. I could "redirect" the session so it writes to another session, like `session_id("trash")`, but that would cause a lot of PHP (Apache) connections to try to write to the same session "file", which I want to avoid.

I'm highly simplifying the problem here, we're actually storing sessions in Memcached and this is a complex codebase. So I don't want to be sending unnecessary "trash" sessions to the Memcached server all the time.

Comment: This challenge may have been formidable in 2011 when question was asked.  I got lucky and saw a Linked question.  Basically since php 5.6.0 and higher versions, placing 1 line of code "session_abort()" at the end of the block where you determine it is undesired to write a session file, prevents that!  Tested on 7.0.33 and works perfectly reliably.  Note that, in the case of a session file having been read and a session_start() was what gave you the session you are working with - and you desire to end using session_abort(); in that case you save a malforned sess_ file being made.  Bonus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't actually determined if this method prevents writing the session to the session store, but here's the solution I finally used:

```
session_id( 'trash' ); // or call session_regenerate_id() as someone else suggested
$_SESSION = array(); // clear the session variables for 'trash'.
```

I'm hoping this has the effect that nothing will get written, but I'm guessing it still will write a blank file, because PHP can't know that sess_trash isn't already there.

If you want to completely avoid writing the session, you'll have to use a custom session handler in PHP and set a global flag to prevent writing the session.

Answer (score 2):

From PHP.net,
[session_regenerate_id](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-regenerate-id.php) 
 will replace the current session id with a new one, and keep the
 current session information.

[session_unset](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-unset.php) will free all registered variables
[session_unregister ( string $name )](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-unregister.php) will unregister a specific variable

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to unset or unregister existing session variables. `session_regenerate_id` does the same kind of thing as what I suggested with `session_id("trash")` - but I'd like to avoid writing the session array entirely.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably use something with [session_set_save_handler](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php) to put dummy functions in for session handling.

```
<?php
function fakeIt() {
    return true;
}
session_set_save_handler("fakeIt", "fakeIt", "fakeIt", "fakeIt", "fakeIt", "fakeIt");
```

Comment: This is a great idea, and I tried it. Unfortunately you have to call `session_set_save_handler` BEFORE `session_start` otherwise it has no effect. I don't know whether to throw out the session or not until after it has already started.

Comment: You may need to write a wrapper method for your memcached session write to check a 'trash' flag.

Comment: Yeah, possibly, only problem is that we use the native memcached session save handler, I wonder if it's possible to wrap just the 'write' method, while continuing to use the native handler for the other methods.

Answer (score 0):

There is `session_write_close()`. It dumps out the session array to storage and then "closes" it - $_SESSION will still be available and read/writeable, but any changes will no longer be saved, unless you do a `session_start()` again later on within the script.

Comment: good idea, but unfortunately there are changes to the $_SESSION that have already been made that I want to "throw out"

Comment: Then do the write_close before you do those disposable changes. It can be done at any time after the initial session_start call.

Comment: I can't - I don't know whether I need to throw out the session data or not until well-after those $_SESSION properties are changed. I'd also like to avoid writing to the session at all if possible, since it would send dead data over the network (to the "trash" session).

Comment: PHP only dumps the session to storage when the script exits or you do a session_write_close(). If you have 'garbage' data, you can always just unset it from $_SESSION as part of the script shutdown, which'd prevent it from being sent over the memcache server. Writing something into $_SESSION does NOT instantly sent it to memcache. While the script's running, it's just an array variable like any other - it just happens to get persisted for you automatically.

Comment: Even if I knew what data changed so that I could restore it or unset it (which I don't), the solution I want would not write data back to the session store at all.