# How to avoid saving PHP session to disk under certain circumstances

Tags: php

I'm working on a quite complex PHP site that store lot of data in the $_SESSION. A standard request involves calling lot of functions that updates the $_SESSION. Exceptions may be thrown at any point of the computation, leaving the data in the $_SESSION inconsistent.

I must avoid inconsistency, data must be saved only if the computation reaches the end. AFAIK PHP writes the session to a file at the end of the script, so if I can prevent it from doing it I should be able to maintain consistency and find the $_SESSION exactly how it was before the crashed call next time I call it, right?

How can I do that?
I've read that session_set_save_handler() may be the right way to go but I don't want to implement my own way to store the session, I'm fine with how PHP does it, I just want to be able to prevent it under certain circumstances (Exceptions).

Solving the problem by serializing a copy of all data at the beginning of every call to be able to eventually restore it is not an option because of performances (there's quite a lot of data). Also I don't have much control over the whole system so I can't do any "important" refactoring of the code.

Comment: [session_abort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-abort.php) or [session_reset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-reset.php)  if you're on >= 5.6.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Mark Baker said in a comment, the answer was simply:

> session_abort() or session_reset() if you're on >= 5.6.0

Poor google results for the query: "avoid saving PHP session disk" and this SO question: [How to prevent a started PHP session from writing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7367756/how-to-prevent-a-started-php-session-from-writing) mislead me into believing the solution was much harder.